# Python subprocess calls not working after making it a package

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pytest, setuptools

1. Just to learn more about socket programming, I am creating a simple program to run commands on a server remotely. The clients can run programs such as `pwd`, `ls`, etc on the server and get output on the client.
2. It worked fine as tested on `localhost`. The repo is [here](https://github.com/utkjad/RemoteAccessUtility/tree/master)
3. Now, I am trying to create a simple package for the same. the structure of the tool is as follows

   ```
   ├── bin
   │   ├── client
   │   └── server
   ├── client
   │   ├── client.py
   │   └── __init__.py
   ├── MANIFEST.in
   ├── README.rst
   ├── server
   │   ├── config-file
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   └── server.py
   └── setup.py
   ```

Link to `server\__init__.py` is [here](https://gist.github.com/utkjad/8e8568da953c3c9fae1a98a3ff3848ba). And the link to the `server\server.py` is [here](https://gist.github.com/utkjad/29e000c646acfb597c6b582bbf2871be). The `setup.py` has an entry for the script `server`. This script does nothing but `import server`. Everything works as before except the calls to `subprocess.check_output`. Every statement before calls to `subprocess` is executed as before. But, calls to `subprocess` does absolutely nothing. It does not produce any exception or error.

What exactly is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: what is the problem specifically?

Comment: @user2682863 I did update the question.

Comment: is `check_call` working? Are the print statements after `check_output` called?

Comment: Nope. `check_call` and `check_output` both are not called. I am not sure if I should say that it does not get called. One thing for sure - Everything gets executed before any call made to `subprocess`. It just stops there without any error or exception.

Comment: what happens if you use `Popen` instead?